# Dockerfile build error and writes to another folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I made a dockerfile like this

```
FROM hyeshik/tailseeker:latest
RUN rm /opt/tailseeker/conf/defaults.conf
COPY /Users/Downloads/defaults.conf /opt/tailseeker/conf/
COPY /Users/Downloads/level2/* /opt/tailseeker/refdb/level2/
COPY /Users/Downloads/level3/* /opt/tailseeker/refdb/level3/
```

My /Users/Downloads/ folder also has other folders named input

When I ran

```
docker build -f /Users/Downloads/Dockerfile /Users/Downloads/
```

I get an error saying

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 126.8 GB
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /input/Logs/Log.00.xml: no space left on device
```

One strange thing here is why is it trying to write to the input folder? And the other one is why does it complain about no space left on device. I have a 1TB disk and only 210GB of it is used. I also used qemu-img and resized my Docker.qcow2. Here is the info of my Docker.qcow2

```
image:/Users/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 214G (229780750336 bytes)
disk size: 60G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: true
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

Can anyone please help me to copy the contents from my /Users/Downloads folder into the docker image by using that dockerfile above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`build` starts by creating a tarball from the context directory (in your case `/Users/Downloads/`) and sending that tarball to the server. The tarball is created in the tmp directory, which is probably why you're running out of space when trying to build.

When you're working with large datasets the recommended approach is to use a volume. You can use a bind mount volume to mount the files from the host.

If the files you're trying to add aren't that large, you might need to use a `.dockerignore` to ignore other files under `/Users/Downloads`.

You can also start the docker daemon with an alternative temp directory using `$DOCKER_TMPDIR`

Comment: can I directly copy the files from my localhost to the image without building? Let's say my directory contents has folders input, tocopy1, tocopy2, output.txt. If I want to copy only folders tocopy1(58GB), tocopy2(739MB) and the file output.txt(2KB), can I do it without building? I understand that if I add .dockerignore file to this folder, the input folder will be ignored.

Comment: You can use `docker cp` and  `docker commit` to create an image